# Accessing class containing instance variable from variable reference

Tags: java, javafx

I'm not sure if this deserve a question but here it is.

If I have some Class, let's say

```
public class myClass{
   Button btn = new Button;
   btn.setOnMouseEvent(myHandler);
   Text txt = "hello";
}
```

Now if the user triggers the event I'll execute some code in myHandler. In there i need to access the `txt` variable but I only have a reference to the `button` via `event.getSource()`.
So how can I obtain a reference to the class containing the object beeing returned by `event.getSource()`?

Edit : Ideas about the title are also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple:

when an event handler instance X depends on some Y object, then Y needs to be made available to X.

For example by:

- adding a Y field to the class of X
- and by then passing a Y instance when doing `new X(someY);` for example

In other words: when your MyClass (class names should go UpperCase!) instantiates the `myHandler` object, it could pass "itself" (via `this` to the handler). Of course, that can lead to circular dependencies (bad), one way out of that:

- Y implements `SomeInterface`
- the handler only gets to know `SomeInterface`, and it never knows or cares that the `SomeInterface` instance passed to it ... happens to be of type Y.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are the one who crated MyHandler and if you can still modify the class then below style can be helpfull:


public class myClass{
   Button btn = new Button;
   Text txt = "hello";
   MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();

   myHandler.setMsg(txt );
   btn.setOnMouseEvent(myHandler);

}
class MyHandler {
    private msg;
    public setMsg(String msg){
      this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```